# Using environment variables in gradle.properties file

Tags: java, gradle, environment-variables

I'm trying to set "org.gradle.java.home" property in `gradle.properties` file to run my Gradle project on Java 8 while the rest of my system uses Java 7. Hence, `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to JDK 7 and not 8.

The problem is that I can't hardcode it to the properties file because other developers might have a different path or version of Java 8. So, I wanted to use an *environment variable* in the properties file like this:

```
org.gradle.java.home=MY_PROJECT_GRADLE_JAVA_HOME
```

That didn't work.

Does anybody know how can I use environment variables in `gradle.properties` or has another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit your gradlew.bat file, and make all developers use this (wrapper) gradle, and not local installation.
Edit it, and anywhere it uses the JAVA_HOME use your env variable instead.

Comment: This will work, but note that if you update your gradle version used by the wrapper, these scripts can get overwritten, so be aware that you'll need to update the wrapper scripts following a version upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work. One possible solutions is to save hardcoded property to user's `gradle.properties`. Extract from docs:

> You can also add properties to your project objects using properties
>   files. You can place a gradle.properties file in the Gradle user home
>   directory (defined by the “GRADLE_USER_HOME” environment variable,
>   which if not set defaults to USER_HOME/.gradle) or in your project
>   directory.

Comment: For those interested, this is the source: https://www.githang.com/gradledoc/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties

Comment: Noteworthy (from same source):  
"The properties file in the user's home directory has precedence over property files in the project directories."