# Jenkins -Gradle -Java

Tags: arrays, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to parameterize my build in Jenkins by taking two variables and pass it to gradle build file which should finally be used by my java file. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

See [Jenkins, Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build):

> Sometimes, it is useful/necessary to have your builds take several "parameters".
>
> [...]
>
> The parameters are available as environment <s>parameters</s>variables. So e.g. a shell ($FOO, %FOO%) or Ant ( ${env.FOO} ) can access these values.

[Correction by me.]

Those variables are available throughout the build so your Gradle build file can use them.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to access these jenkins parameters in gradle.properties file? If yes how would I do that?

Comment: @user5477804 Seems not to be possible: [Using environment variables in gradle.properties file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28938712/1744774).